# calling "loading JSON" methods of an activity class in service class

Tags: android, json, methods, service, android-activity

I am trying calling "loading JSON" methods of an activity class in service class

The above is the method in  MainActivity class

```
public JSONObject loadJSONFromRawResource()
 {
  .....
 }
```

And i want to call that in service class,so i wrote this in service class.

```
MainActivity m=new MainActivity(); 
m.loadJSONFromRawResource();
```

But now i am getting an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service 
java.lang.NullPointerException


03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service             com.example.file.Merge: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2587)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.example.file.MainActivity.loadJSONFromRawResource(MainActivity.java:73)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.example.file.Merge.onCreate(Merge.java:50)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2577)
03-05 03:27:57.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: please post all logcat error

Comment: **"MainActivity m=new MainActivity();"** - You cannot do this. It's not possible to create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. Put your JSON loader method into a helper class and use that.

Comment: but its working fine when i am calling other methods from another activity class.

Comment: Never do that - you are really going to give your self problems if you try accessing methods in an `Activity` from anywhere other than the `Activity` itself. An `Activity` should be self-contained and shouldn't be treated as a general worker class.

Comment: Then how should i access methods from an Activity class in Service class?

Comment: As I said - create a helper class and access the methods in that from both the `Activity` and the `Service`.

Comment: but i want everything in back end..so i am using service class as merging class through which i can run all the activity classes